# How to change progress bar when selected different options

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I am making a simulation game. There are five variables, month, money, stress, job, and happiness. I created a selection option. I want to change the variables according to the different options. This is what I have so far for the selection option. I want the different variables to change as I select the different options and click next. For example, if selected high, relax at home, and part-time, the stress progress bar will increase and happiness will decrease. How do I do that? Also the month would increase by 1 everytime I click next.

```
<div id="monthlyworkplan" class="hidden p-4">
            <h4 align="center">Create This Month's Work Plan</h4>
            <form class="select">
                <div style="padding-top: 10px;">Select work effort:</div> 
                <select class="selectpicker" style="width: 100px" id="workeffort" title="Select">
                  <option>Select</option>
                  <option value="high">High</option>
                  <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                  <option value="low">Low</option>
                </select>
                <div style="padding-top: 10px;">Select after work activity:</div>
                <select class="selectpicker" style="width: 100px" id="afterworkactivity" title="Select">
                  <option>Select</option>
                  <option value="high">Connect with potential client</option>
                  <option value="medium">Relax at home</option>
                  <option value="low">Hang out with friends</option>
                </select>
                <div style="padding-top: 10px;">Select weekend activity:</div>
                <select class="selectpicker" style="width: 100px" id="weekend activity" title="Select">
                  <option>Select</option>
                  <option value="high">Part-time job</option>
                  <option value="medium">Pass out flyers</option>
                  <option value="low">Relax at home</option>
                </select>
                <div id="workefforteffect" style="font-size:11px position:absolute; right:-131px; top:171px;" class="hidden p-4">stress</div>
            </form>
                <button class="btn" id="next">NEXT</button>
```

Comment: This smells like a homework assignment. Regardless, you'll want to do the following: 1) add onclick="myFunction()" to you button. 2) create a function inside a <script> element called "myFunction()" 3) create a variable that gets the <select> value by 'id'. 4) Change the 'innerHTML' of the "progress bar" to your newly declared variable. If none of that made sense, I suggest reading a book about basic JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help you get started with your journey through HTML, CSS, JS hell, here is some basic code working harmoniously to accomplish a simple input/output function.

```css
/* change how the progress bar looks using classes */
.bar { 
  width: 200px; 
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.bar .progress {
  width: 50%;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML with embedded JS -->
<div id="bar" class="bar">
  <div id="progress" class="progress"></div>
</div>

<div id="myForm">
  <select id="selector-1">
    <option value="1">Subtract 10</option>
    <option value="2">Add 10</option>
    <option value="3">Add 20</option>
  </select>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">SUBMIT</button>
</div>

<script>
  function myFunction(){
    //declare selector variables
    var s1 = document.getElementById("selector-1");
    var s1_value = s1.options[s1.selectedIndex].value;
    
    //update progress bar
    var bar = document.getElementById('progress');
    if (s1_value == "1"){ bar.style.width = (bar.offsetWidth - 10) + "px"; }
    else if (s1_value == "2"){ bar.style.width = (bar.offsetWidth + 10) + "px"; }
    else if (s1_value == "3"){ bar.style.width = (bar.offsetWidth + 20) + "px"; }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: thank you, but how do I increase the width by a certain percentage instead of just setting it to a percent?

Comment: You could create a point variable for 'money' with a max 'wallet' size. For instance, if you select '1', then decrease the money by 1 (money = money - 1). The width could then be calculated with a new ratio: bar.style.width = ((money / maxMoney) * 100) + "%";

Comment: what if I just want to increase it by 10%?

Comment: I updated the example to use increments (pixels) rather than a percentage.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get this work for my simulation

Comment: Awesome! In that case, feel free to mark my answer as correct :D